# Jupyter Notebook still truncating pandas columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

So, I have a pandas data frame with two fields

| partition | account_list |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [id1,id2,id3,...] |
| 2 | [id4,id6,id5,...] |

since the list is quite long and I want to see the complete content I'm using

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

louvain_communities.limit(tot_communities).toPandas()
```

nevertheless, as you can see (Jupiter I think) still truncate the column (I had to edit out the data for privacy)

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? I really need to check have the complete list, not truncated, to be shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**max_colwidth** and **max_seq_items** together work.  Code below synthesises **list** with 500 items.   Change the `range()` and you can test however many you want.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("max_colwidth", None)
pd.set_option("max_seq_items", None)
pd.DataFrame([{"partition":i, "account_list":[f"id{j}" for j in range(500)]} for i in range(2)])
```

Comment: How long is your output? Because my columns are of more than 8k characters.

Comment: it's in the code ...  I've updated the answer,  it your list is > 100 items you need to set **max_seq_items** as well